# Monotouch claims-based authentication for connecting to SharePoint/Office 365

Tags: sharepoint, xamarin.ios, claims-based-identity, office365

Fellow devs, does anyone have sample code for authenticating against Office 365 (claimes-based)?
I need to access SharePoint lists from an iPad app that I am building with Monotouch/Monotouch.Dialog.
Thanks in advance for your help.
Fred

Answer (score 0):

If it's Office 365 post upgrade (=2013), you need to use [SharePointOnlineCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.sharepointonlinecredentials.aspx). I've never tried to use it with MonoTouch, but it has few dependencies..

Here is how to use it:

```
var creds = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, pass);
var cookie = creds.GetAuthenticationCookie(uri);
```

Then you can inject the cookie in your webservices calls.